# oracle with spring boot not fetching by primary key

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I have written a spring boot app with oracle db.

Below is my entiry class.

```
@Entity
 public class SystemTypeLookup{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected UUID id;


    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    }
```

And in passing my own UUID as primary key value.
In oracle db ID is considered as **RAW** and the UUID stored in oracle is differently. 
There is no **-** separation in oracle and all the UUID chars are in upper case.
[image]
[image]

When i try to find the entity using primary key it is not fetching the row with id. I'm always getting null.

```
  @Resource(name = "coreRepository")
    private ErpEntityRepository coreRepositoryBase;

SystemTypeLookup systemTypeLookup =  coreRepositoryBase.findOne("WHERE o.id='"+id+"'", SystemTypeLookup.class);
```

when is pass **76c03cd9-3d96-40c5-8df9-aad8f2369453** as id value then the oracle will insert the id without '-' and all chars will be in upper case.
So how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use parameters in your query and second make sure that the id you are passing is of type UUID and not String.

Comment: I'm using parameters in the query and yes they are UUID only.